# Using a For Loop to create a column in each dataset in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list that contains 6 data frames:

```
set.seed(3310)
Q2Data <- data.frame("ID"=rep(3500+sort(sample(1:100,10,FALSE)),5),
                     "Trial"=rep(1:5,each=10),"AffectRange"=sample(20:30,50,TRUE),
                     "X"=runif(50)*20,"Y"=rnorm(50))
myDataList <- lapply(1:6,function(i){
  if(i!=3){
    Q2Data2 <- data.frame("ID"=Q2Data$ID,"Trial"=Q2Data$Trial,
                          "AffectRange"=sample(-10:10,50,TRUE)+40-i^2,
                          "X"=runif(50)*20,"Y"=rnorm(50))
    return(Q2Data2)
  } else {
    return(Q2Data)
  }
})
```

I want to use a for loop to add a column in each data frame within myDataList that has the name: Session (so that dataset 1 only has 1's, dataset 2 only has 2's, and so forth). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please keep your question as it is after it has been solved. It is useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop over the sequence of the `list`, extract the `list` with the index and assign the sequence value to the column 'Session'

```
for(i in seq_along(myDataList)) myDataList[[i]]$Session <- i
```

-checking

```
lapply(myDataList, function(x) head(x, 2))
#[[1]]
#    ID Trial AffectRange         X          Y Session
#1 3503     1          33 17.913372 0.03774691       1
#2 3506     1          40  6.414134 0.95953380       1

#[[2]]
#    ID Trial AffectRange         X        Y Session
#1 3503     1          35 4.2334412 0.316318       2
#2 3506     1          29 0.4523345 1.096811       2

#[[3]]
#    ID Trial AffectRange         X          Y Session
#1 3503     1          24 11.529405 -0.7178684       3
#2 3506     1          28  5.246109 -1.0847689       3

#[[4]]
#    ID Trial AffectRange         X          Y Session
#1 3503     1          14  9.583683  0.8305489       4
#2 3506     1          28 14.892399 -0.7573065       4

#[[5]]
#    ID Trial AffectRange        X         Y Session
#1 3503     1          15 12.42385 0.7315943       5
#2 3506     1          18  3.76688 0.2803606       5

#[[6]]
#    ID Trial AffectRange         X          Y Session
#1 3503     1          13  5.431017 -0.1039454       6
#2 3506     1           5 11.363984 -0.8118451       6
```

---

Or another option is

```
myDataList <- Map(cbind, myDataList, Session = seq_along(myDataList))
```

---

Or using `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap(myDataList, ~ .x %>%
                        mutate(Session = .y))
```